# Saving data to firebase database sequentially

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write `data1` to my database and only after this data is saved I want to write `data2`. What happens is, I want to make sure that `data2` will be at the database only if `data1` is sure to be saved already.

I thought that something like the code below would work, but it seems it doesn't. Any ideas on how exactly to do this?

What I tried and didn't work:

```
dbData1Ref = firebase.database().ref('data1Node').push();
dbData1Ref.set(data1).then(()=>{
    dbData2Ref = firebase.database().ref('data2Node').push();
    dbData2Ref.set(data2).then(()=>{
        goToSuccess('everything saved correctly');
    }).catch(()=>{
        goToError('error with saving data2')
    });
}).catch(()=>{
    goToError('error with saving data1');
});
```

When I tried the above, I would always get `data1` saved to the database but not `data2`. Furthermore, I would get "catched" only by `goToError('error with saving data1')` and never by `goToError('error saving data2')`.